# Finding the closest PMS color with a hex color?

Tags: php, colors, hex, rgb, pantone

Is there a way to match Hex/RGB colors to the closest PMS (Pantone Matching system) colors?

I'm trying to think of a way to code this, but have no idea where to even get started.

Comment: If there's a database of hex codes and corresponding colour names (assuming you want them) somewhere, then get started with that. The only other option is to scan each physical colour tile and convert it to hex manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you'd get the [RGB values for the PMS colors](http://goffgrafix.com/pantone-rgb-100.php), then use one of the several [Delta-E formulas](http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=DELT&H=06#text6) to find the differences (and, obviously, choose whichever gave the smallest difference).

Answer (score 1):

There's a ready class with all the values preset that let's you easily convert colors between formats.

Here you can find it: [colour](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/804-PHP-Class-for-converting-color-formats.html)

Comment: Is there anything like this exists for Dot Net?